# How to use analytics custom dimensions for tracking pageviews by author?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I am trying to configure my blog and the analytics code for it. There are multiple authors in my blog. What I am trying to do is aggregate the number of views by separate authors.

This is what I did

Went to my Analytics Admin and from there, for my Web Property I created a Custom Dimension from Custom Definitions. [image: my custom dimension]

The custom dimension is creted with Index 1 and the scope is "Hit". It is shown in the image above.

Then for the analytics code, that I place in the posts of my Blog, I placed the following code:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-XX', 'myblog.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview', {
    'dimension1': 'Author Name'
  });
</script>
```

I've placed my value for UA-XXXXXXX-XX, myblog.com and Author Name.

It has been almost a month since I've been scratching my head and hoping that the code would work. But I don't see any stats in my Analytics > Audience > Custom > Custom Variables / User Defined. I hope it is there where I am supposed to look.

So, where did I go wrong? I would be highly greatful if someone would point out what I missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've named your custom dimension "Custom Dimension Name" when it should be "Author" and you'll need to add the server-side variable as the value for dimension1.

For example, if you're using WordPress, your code would look like:

```
  ga('send', 'pageview', {
    'dimension1':'<?php the_author(); ?>'
  });
```

Also, your custom dimension scope should be set to `hit`.

Comment: In the 'Author name' area, there is already a server side variable that echoes the name of the author.

And the name of my custom dimension is Author and it is hit.

Comment: Ah, pretty sure I read your post wrong. Try creating a custom report to look at your custom dimension. Custom dimensions and metrics aren't available in standard reporting.

Comment: Thank you very much. The codes were all right, I only didn't know where to look in Analytics.